# Al iniciar no renderiza correctamente el mapa

Tags: javascript, css, map, leaflet, leafletjs

Tengo un problema super raro con Leaflet... Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación en un navegador la primera carga del mapa no se realiza de manera correcta, como si le faltara renderizar partes del mapa, pero lo más raro no es eso, sino que cuando presiono f12 para inspeccionar en consola que está pasando, mágicamente el mapa renderiza completo y todo funciona bien.

La verdad es que no le encuentro sentido y tampoco encontré nada de información al respecto, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con esto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA: Ya probé con funciones asincrónicas y promesas en javascript, para que primero cargue el mapa y después los marcadores que ven en pantalla, pero tampoco lo resuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No olvides mostrar un [repro] del problema en cuestión. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @padaleiana es un desarrollo que ya estaba hecho con la api de google maps y tuve que cambiarlo a leaflet. El tamaño de los divs que contienen al mapa están definidos con contenedores de less

Comment: Ok. Entonces, para reproducir el error, de nuevo: muestra un [repro].

Comment: Por cierto, [¿es este tu caso?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153270)

Comment: Me sucede lo mismo pro con un Modal, ya sea de bootstrap o con la etiqueta < Dialog > al ejecutar el JavaScript que activa el modal el mapa se desrenderiza, pero cuando lo cargo directamente junto con los elementos de la pagina, sin modal y sin codigo JS adicional para ejecutarlo, entonces funciona muy bien el mapa. Hasta el momento no encuentro la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución, forzando la actualización del mapa para que no espere a que se haga el redimencionado de pantalla.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('exampleModal');

// Escuchar el evento mostrado del modal
modal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // Forzar una actualización del mapa al mostrar el modal
    map.invalidateSize();
});
```